# How can I force django.allauth to require an email

Tags: django, django-allauth

In my django project I am using django.allauth to manage my users. I want the user to provide both a user name and an email address.

If I use the allauth SignupView it the email field must be filled, however if I override it with my own view, it does not make it mandatory. What am I missing?

**settings.py**

```
# User model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'

# django-allauth settings
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/home'
SITE_ID = 1

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username_email' 
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True 
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True 
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
```

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    logged_in = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_active_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    login_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('username', 'email')
```

**urls.py**

```
from .views import MySignupView

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', MySignupView.as_view(), name='signup'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from allauth.account.views import SignupView
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm
SIGNUP_SUCCESS = 'You have successfully signed up!'

class MySignupView(SignupView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'account/signup.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        messages.success(self.request, SIGNUP_SUCCESS)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["button_text"] = 'Sign Up'
        return context
```

Answer (score 1):

In `django.allauth` you don't need to create a custom form for a username and an email address.

If you want to create a custom form anyway, you need to add `function def signup (self, request, user):` in your `CustomUserCreationForm`:

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm

class CustomUserCreationForm(SignupForm):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'date_of_birth')

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.date_of_birth = self.cleaned_data['date_of_birth']
        user.save()
```

Then, in your `settings.py` point to this form:

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'yourapp.forms.CustomUserCreationForm'
```

See [django.allauth configuration](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html?highlight=ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS#configuration) for more info.